# BlackBerry - Register for Push

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have developed a BlackBerry App that has a minor chat feature. The App receives messages from the server via push messaging. The very first time when the App is loaded onto a handset, it loads with the first screen as the `Register Screen`. Once the user clicks on `Register`, the app would register on the company website along with push messaging feature. After this the user is directed to the main screen and the register screen will not pop up.

My question is; if the user closes the app and reopens it AND/OR shuts down his handset and reopens the app, would the app be still registered for push messaging or the registration has to happen every time the app is opened?

Comment: if the registration for push message is success, then the user will get push notifications until he unregistered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the **BlackBerry** Push Service (and not some custom, non-BlackBerry/RIM solution), then you should only need to register a device once.

I'll also point you back to an answer to [a previous question you asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18606610/119114) (note especially the part about *alternate entry points*).

Also, you can take a look [at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15947917/119114) (read both answers) ...

... and maybe [this one, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935310/119114).